# Xamarin distribution on iPhone or simulator error, iOS 13

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

When I try to test my app on my iPhone or the simulator I receive this compiler error:

> Can't resolve the reference 'UIKit.UIColor
>   UIKit.UIColor::get_SystemBackgroundColor()', referenced from the
>   method 'System.Void
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.SwipeViewRenderer::SetBackgroundColor(Xamarin.Forms.Color)'
>   in 'Xamarin.iOS, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065'.

Can someone help me?

Comment: You might wanna add more details where this happens and what is the exception thrown if any!!

Comment: This happens when i try to compile the app. There isn't exception trwed

Comment: It seems like this error is coming from library SwipeViewRenderer, remove it and see if the error still appears?

Comment: Does this problem go away if you downgrade the iOS SDK version in your iOS project properties from 13 to 12?

Comment: @MuhammadAdeelShoukat there isn't a library in the ios folder. But there is a class  with this name in the android one.

Comment: @MouseOnMars i have already tryed but doesn't work

Comment: Can you build one of the VS template solutions (e.g. single page app)? Also are you using the latest version of VS 2019 & XCode?

Comment: @AlessandroZago Hi , could you share code of `SwipeView` and `SwipeViewRenderer` , it will be helful to check where problem is .

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT i can't find SwipeView and SwipeViewRenderer

Comment: @AlessandroZago OK , do you have selected [Link SDK assemblies only](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/linker?tabs=windows#link-sdk-assemblies-only) when distribute application .